# convert value to different level

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql

I have an amount in postgres table which I can get through query `select sum (price) from xyz` I want to convert this value in different level like if I got 2000 it convert to

```
Price > 2000
1000  - 2000
500   - 1000
Price < 500
```

I want to show it in filter of the website... I am using (postgres, codeiginiter, javascript, jquery) can any of the language help me to create that format

Comment: here `Price` in first row is a string ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to build, nor what your problem is/where you need help. Are you trying to group the results you get from postgres into predefined ranges?

Comment: i have this query                                                                                 
        SELECT generate_series(10000 , 2001,-((10000)/5)) AS left, generate_series(10000 , 2001,-((10000)/5)) AS right  .... both right and left column shows same value...  i just want right column start with second value and last row show 0

Answer (score 0):

```
finaly create thanx to all

 select t1.row_number,t1.left,t2.right from
(SELECT row_number() over(),f2.* from(
SELECT generate_series(max(purchase_price::integer) , min(purchase_price::integer),-((max(purchase_price::integer))/5)) AS left FROM tbl_products) f2) t1
join
(SELECT row_number() over(),f.* from(
(SELECT  generate_series(max(purchase_price::integer) , min(purchase_price::integer),-((max(purchase_price::integer))/5)) AS right FROM tbl_products offset 1)
union all
(select '0' as right)) f)t2
on t1.row_number =t2.row_number
```

Answer (score 0):

> i have this query `SELECT generate_series(10000 , 2001,-((10000)/5)) AS left, generate_series(10000 , 2001,-((10000)/5)) AS right` .... both right and left column shows same value... i just want right column start with second value and last row show 0

why are you doing this with SQL?

How about something like

```js
var arr = [];
for(var i=10000; i >= 2001; ) 
   arr.push([i, i -= 10000/5]);
   
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

`... and last row show 0` contradicts your end-value of `2001`. Your function call will generate the series `[10000, 8000, 6000, 4000]` not even 2000 is in there. So wich one is it? 0 or 2001?

Or this, if the previous code looks "hacky" to you:

```
for(var i=10000, j; i >= 2001; i=j){
   var j = i - 10000/5;
   arr.push([i, j]);
}
```